# How to call scripts within fancyBox popups without choking the browser?

Tags: jquery, dom, fancybox

Behold the following table ...

[image]

Clicking any row opens a non-modal fancyBox (v2.1.4) with that row's details ...

[image]

The fancyBox is called like so ...

```
function showBox( url, title, modal ){
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'ajax',
        href: url,
        title: title,
        padding: 20,
        modal: modal,
        afterShow: function(){
            pageInit();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

So far so good, it works fine. Except that fancyBox becomes increasingly non-responsive. Initial popups respond within a half second. After 5 popups, the response is delayed about a second. 10 clicks = 2 seconds. 20 = 5 seconds. The problem is not fancyBox, it's my `pageInit()` function, which looks like this:

```
function pageInit() {
    // autosize textareas
    $('.autoresize').autosize();
    // buttonsets
    $('.buttonset').buttonset();
    // checkbox + radio
    $('input:checkbox, input:radio').not( $('div.buttonset input') ).uniform();
    // dates
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
        });
    // hoverable tables
    $('table.hoverable').on( 'click', 'tbody tr', function(e){
        var $url = $(this).data('url');
        var $title = $(this).data('title');
        var $modal = $(this).data('modal') ? true : false;
        if (typeof $title !== 'undefined') { // has title, call showbox()
            showBox( $url, $title, $modal );
        } else if (typeof $url !== 'undefined') { // url but no title, load page
            if (e.metaKey) window.open( $url ); // command click .. open in new tab
            else window.location.href = $url; // open in current window
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('a, input:checkbox, input:radio').click( function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); // prevent action of hoverable tr click!

    // zebra striping
    $('table.zebra > tbody > tr:visible:even').css('background', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)');
    $('table.zebra > tbody > tr:visible:odd').css('background', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)');
}
```

I'm using many UI enhancements and input formatting tools, such as *autosize*, *uniform*, jQuery UI's *buttonset* and *datepicker*, and a few homebrew functions. Having these in the popup improves usability and continuity. So I call `pageInit()` once in the parent document, and then again in the `afterShow:` of each fancyBox popup.

Obviously, calling these elements repeatedly is problematic. There are layers of DOM and scripts going on that make things a bit confusing. What's the right way to use call jQuery for pop-ups without re-initializing things over and over again?

Comment: I can work-around the problem by making these dialogs MODAL, reloading the page after UPDATE or CANCEL ... but that's a clumsy UX, and defeats the purpose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do something like :

```
modalInit(elem){
  $(elem).find('.autoresize').autosize(); 
 ....
}
function showBox( url, title, modal ){
  $.fancybox({
    ....
    modal: modal,
    afterShow: function(){
        modalInit($(modal)); // or whatever you html object is
    }
  });
 return false;
}
```